# Should I create multiple Firebase projects or add multiple apps to a single Firebase project?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm working on a SaaS in which customers can brand their own app. I'm using Firebase for Push Notifications and Dynamic Links.
Now, I'm not sure if I should create a new Firebase project for each customer or if I should just add multiple apps to one single Firebase project.
Are there any limitations on how many apps can be added to one single project?
I've also read that there are limitations on how many projects can be added to Firebase (for free). Any idea how much it cost if I reach that limit?

Any recommendations?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you only use it for notification and Links? Don't intend to use any of the databases?

Comment: @GabrielNexT Yes, we don't use any of the Firebase databases and also do not plan to do so in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, you can have a maximum of [30 apps in a project](https://firebase.google.com/support/faq#apps-per-project), but you can request to increase your number.

In your case, I recommend that you use only one application and prepare it to handle multiple clients. Cloud messaging has a great integration with Google Analytics, in GA you can define a target audience.

Let's say you have a customer who is company A and 50 users use your SaaS at that company. You can define in Google Analytics the target audience "members of company A" and trigger notification only for these users. Remembering that this has to be done carefully to prevent users from receiving unexpected notifications.

Also, you can use Messaing Topics, where you can subscribe a user to a topic and then trigger a notification to all users subscribed to that topic.

Firebase has a very extensive documentation, recently they posted on the blog an example that can help you.

[Targeting Audiences with Cloud Messaging - Firebase Blog](https://firebase.blog/posts/2022/12/targeting-audiences-with-fcm)

In the case of Dynamic Link, I don't think it will be a problem.